# Used Premises/Axioms in Z3 TPTP proofs

Tags: z3

When using Z3 on TPTP files (e.g. http://www.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/cgi-bin/SeeTPTP?Category=Problems&Domain=SYN&File=SYN054+1.p) is there a way to find out which axioms were used to prove the conjecture?
Alternatively, can Z3 produce TPTP proofs?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Z3 includes limited TPTP support. 
It does not track axiom names or produce proofs in the TPTP format. 
Z3 offers rich support for SMT-LIB2 format and it produces proofs 
in a format that can be digested by SMT-LIB2 parsers.